# How can I launch an EMR using SPOT Block using boto?

Tags: python-2.7, boto, emr, boto3

How can I launch an EMR using spot block (AWS) using boto ? I am trying to launch it using boto but I cannot find any parameter --block-duration-minutes in boto, I am unable to find how to do this using boto3.

Answer (score 2):

EMR does not currently support EC2 Spot duration block.I have checked with EMR team as well on this. Works only with EC2 Service for now. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-spot-blocks-for-defined-duration-workloads/

Comment: This answer is now outdated.  EC2 spot instances are now supported in EMR.

Answer (score 1):

According to the boto3 documentation, yes it does support spot blocks.

> BlockDurationMinutes (integer) --
>   The defined duration for Spot instances (also known as Spot blocks) in minutes. When specified, the Spot instance does not terminate before the defined duration expires, and defined duration pricing for Spot instances applies. Valid values are 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, or 360. The duration period starts as soon as a Spot instance receives its instance ID. At the end of the duration, Amazon EC2 marks the Spot instance for termination and provides a Spot instance termination notice, which gives the instance a two-minute warning before it terminates.

Iniside the `LaunchSpecifications` dictionary, you need to assign a value to `BlockDurationMinutes`.  However, the maximum value is 360 (6 hours) for a spot block.